# Response <403> Despite Correct Authorization in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, httpresponse, http-status-code-403

I am trying to send a post request to a URL, I did this in python with the following code and it worked like a charm and I got a [Response <200>], but since I needed to use this in a website, I switched over to JS and tried to recreate the same functionality, but for some reason I'm getting a [Response <403>] even tho all my auth tokens and headers and everything is same as the python code.

Python Code -

```py
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/801784356711956522/messages"
    auth = ""
    headers = {"Authorization": auth,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'referer': "https://discord.com/channels/801784356217421874/801784356711956522"}
    payload = {'content': 'Test' , 'nounce': 802056256326991872, 'tts': False}
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print(response)
```

JavaScript Code -

```js
onst url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/801784356711956522/messages"
const auth = ""
const headers = {"Authorization": auth,
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                 'referer': "https://discord.com/channels/801784356217421874/801784356711956522"}

const options = {
    headers : headers, 
}                

const data = JSON.stringify({'content':"Test" , 'nounce': 802056256326991872, 'tts': false})

process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your python code, you made a **POST** request but in JavaScript code, you made a **GET** request because you did not provide the method option.

It is specified in [https.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) options documentation:

> method  A string specifying the HTTP request method. Default:
> 'GET'.

To make POST request modify like this

```js
const options = {
    headers : headers,
    method: "POST"
}
```

Also, you need to add URL since you did not provide hostname and path in the options.

```js
const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Well for some reason, thats giving me a status code of 400, which I dont understand the reason of since its working exactly fine in python and i'm essentially posting the same request

Comment: I realized that you did not provide a URL parameter to your request. `https.request(url, options, (res) => {` can you try like this?

Comment: Woah, I didn't notice that, thankss! its working now. You could just update your answer to include this too along the the `method: "POST"` thing so  I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

```js
const querystring = require('querystring');
const https = require('https');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'domain.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/yow-path',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Content-Length': postData.length
     }
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```